# Forecasting using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Forecasting has always been a debatable topic. Let us think that we have a time-series data and we want to forecast 10 months beyond our data. We know that forecasting is another topic and predictions are another topic, both have their own style. y will be my complete data and training_y is my training data and test is my test data (which is equal to the forecast horizon, 10 observation). During the forecast in R, let us simulate like this:

```
my_model<-auto.arima(training_y,trace = TRUE)
my_predictions<-forecast(my_model,h=10)
autoplot(my_predictions)
accuracy(my_predictions,test)
```

So, in here we did not do any future forecast, it is the test data and we get the accuracy but after determining the best model comparing by the test data, should we directly use the all data (y) to forecast future? What will be the evaluation for this approach? For example:

```
my_model<-auto.arima(y,trace = TRUE)
my_predictions<-forecast(my_model,h=10)
autoplot(my_predictions)
```

Now, it will give me the future values because I use the complete data, there is no training/test.

So, should I do train/test split first to determine best model for the data then should I do forecast process with all data, is this approach correct? and what is the final evaluation for the approach without train/test split?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct approach. You use train/test splits when developing and estimating the expected accuracy, and you use full data set when forecasting the future.

There is no further evaluation you can do at that point, other than wait 10 months and see how it went.

Comment: thanks a lot but they are also using tsCV() function  after the forecasting using full dataset so what is the point of that also?

Comment: I don't see a point using that after getting the forecast for the future.